# Chrome Extension does not load content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, content-script

I am making a new chrome extension in a new folder and i create only 2 files :

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "My Cool Extension",
  "version": "0.1",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": [
        "*://*/*"
      ],
      "js": ["onpage.js"],
      "run_at": "document_end"
    }
  ]
}
```

and onpage.js

```
alert("hello world");
```

i insert the new extension in chrome 53.0.2785.101 (64-bit) on OSX.
The extension is added on my extension bar, but the alert never appears.

Comment: Have you verified the path works? Try something you know will match

Comment: yeap, i tried tons of different paths, even copying pasting full paths from my server.

Comment: i tried it on a file url too but i mainly use something like this : ```https://electra.teipir.gr/login.php``` and still not working

Comment: The code is correct and it works for me. Try it on a new chrome person/profile. Or even in a separate Chrome Portable/Canary. As for `file://` urls, you need to enable `[x] Allow access to file urls` on chrome://extensions page and probably switch to `<all_urls>` instead of `*://*/*`.